# Sinkhorn algorithm for optimal transport

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to code Sinkhorn algorithm, especially I'm trying to see if I can compute the optimal transportation between two measures when the strengh of the entropic regularization converges to 0.

For exemple let's transport the uniform measure $U$ over $[0;1]$ into the uniform measure $V$ over $[1;2]$. 
The optimal measure for the quadratic coast is $(x,x-1)_{#} U$.

Let's discretize $[0;1]$, the measure $U$, $[1;2]$ and the measure $V$. Using Sinkhorn I'm supposed to get a measure such that the support is in the graphe of the line $y = x-1$. But it didn't so I'm working on it to find what's the problem. I'm going to show you my code and my result maybe someone can help me.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors

#Parameters
N = 10                        #Step of the discritization of [0,1]
stop = 10**-3
Niter = 10**3


def Sinkhorn(C, mu, nu, lamb):
    # lam : strength of the entropic regularization

    #Initialization
    a1 = np.zeros(N)
    b1 = np.zeros(N)
    a2 = np.ones(N)
    b2 = np.ones(N)
    Iter = 0

    GammaB = np.exp(-lamb*C)

    #Sinkhorn
    while (np.linalg.norm(a2) > stop and  np.linalg.norm(b2) > stop and np.linalg.norm(a2) < 1/stop and np.linalg.norm(b2) < 1/stop and Iter < Niter and np.linalg.norm(a1-a2) + np.linalg.norm(b1-b2) > stop ):
        a1 = a2
        b1 = b2
        a2 = mu/(np.dot(GammaB,b1))
        b2 = nu/(np.dot(GammaB.T,a2))
        Iter +=1

    # Compute gamma_star
    Gamma = np.zeros((N,N))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            Gamma[i][j] = a2[i]*b2[j]*GammaB[i][j]
    Gamma /= Gamma.sum()

    return Gamma

## Test between uniform([0;1]) over uniform([1;2])

S = np.linspace(0,1,N, False)  #discritization of [0,1]
T = np.linspace(1,2,N,False)  #discritization of [1,2]

# Discretization of uniform([0;1])
U01 = np.ones(N)
Mass = np.sum(U01)
U01 = U01/Mass

# Discretization uniform([1;2])
U12 = np.ones(N)
Mass = np.sum(U12)
U12 = U12/Mass

# Cost function
X,Y = np.meshgrid(S,T)
C = (X-Y)**2               #Matrix of c[i,j]=(xi-yj)²

def plot_Sinkhorn_U01_U12():

    #plot optimal measure and convergence
    fig = plt.figure()
    for i in range(4):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i+1, projection='3d')
        Gamma_star = Sinkhorn(C, U01, U12, 1/10**i)
        ax.scatter(X, Y, Gamma_star, cmap='viridis', linewidth=0.5)
        plt.title("Gamma_bar({}) between uniform([0,1]) and uniform([1,2])".format(1/10**i))

    plt.show()

    plt.figure()
    for i in range(4):
        plt.subplot(2,2,i+1)
        Gamma_star = Sinkhorn(C, U01, U12, 1/10**i)
        plt.imshow(Gamma_star,interpolation='none')
        plt.title("Gamma_bar({}) between uniform([0,1]) and uniform([1,2])".format(1/10**i))

    plt.show()

    return

# The transport between U01 ans U12 is x -> x-1 so the support of gamma^* is contained in the graph of the function x -> (x,x+1) which is the line y = x+1

plot_Sinkhorn_U01_U12()
```

And what I get.

[image]
[image]

As adviced, this is the output of my code when I'm considerating 1/lamb.

[image: Output]

[image: Output]

It's way more better but still not correct. Here's Gamma_star(125)

```
Gamma_star(125) : 
[[0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.09 0.01]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.01 0.01]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.01]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.01]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.01]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.01]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.01]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.01]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.01]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.01]]
```

We can see that the support of the measure gamma_star is not contained in the line $y = x-1$

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stackoverflow does not support LaTeX. Therefore, I would suggest you to use backticks `\`` instead of `$`, especially because you seems to be using the same notation in the code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the final answer but we're getting closer.

As adviced, I lighten my while condition. For exemple with the only condition

```
while (Iter < Niter):
```

This is what I get :

[image]

[image]

Here is the matrix I got for gamma_star(125) :

```
[[0.08 0.02 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.02 0.06 0.02 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.02 0.06 0.02 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.02 0.06 0.02 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.02 0.06 0.02 0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.02 0.06 0.02 0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.02 0.06 0.02 0.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.02 0.06 0.02 0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.02 0.06 0.02]
 [0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.02 0.08]]
```

It's closer from my expection which is : $\text{Gamma_star}(i,j) = 0$ for $j \ne i-1$

The new code is :

```
import numpy as np
import math
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors

#Parameters
N = 10                        #Step of the discritization of [0,1]
Niter = 10**5

def Sinkhorn(C, mu, nu, lamb):
    # lam : strength of the entropic regularization

    #Initialization
    a1 = np.zeros(N)
    b1 = np.zeros(N)
    a2 = np.ones(N)
    b2 = np.ones(N)
    Iter = 0

    GammaB = np.exp(-lamb*C)

    #Sinkhorn
    while (Iter < Niter):
        a1 = a2
        b1 = b2
        a2 = mu/(np.dot(GammaB,b1))
        b2 = nu/(np.dot(GammaB.T,a2))
        Iter +=1

    # Compute gamma_star
    Gamma = np.zeros((N,N))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            Gamma[i][j] = a2[i]*b2[j]*GammaB[i][j]
    Gamma /= Gamma.sum()

    return Gamma

    ## Test between uniform([0;1]) over uniform([1;2])

    S = np.linspace(0,1,N, False)  #discritization of [0,1]
    T = np.linspace(1,2,N,False)  #discritization of [1,2]

    # Discretization of uniform([0;1])
    U01 = np.ones(N)
    Mass = np.sum(U01)
    U01 = U01/Mass

    # Discretization uniform([1;2])
    U12 = np.ones(N)
    Mass = np.sum(U12)
    U12 = U12/Mass

    # Cost function
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(S,T)
    C = (X-Y)**2               #Matrix of c[i,j]=(xi-yj)²

    def plot_Sinkhorn_U01_U12():

        #plot optimal measure and convergence
        fig = plt.figure()
        for i in range(4):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i+1, projection='3d')
            Gamma_star = Sinkhorn(C, U01, U12, 5**i)
            ax.scatter(X, Y, Gamma_star, cmap='viridis', linewidth=0.5)
            plt.title("Gamma_bar({}) between uniform([0,1]) and uniform([1,2])".format(5**i))
        plt.show()

        plt.figure()
        for i in range(4):
            plt.subplot(2,2,i+1)
            Gamma_star = Sinkhorn(C, U01, U12, 5**i)
            plt.imshow(Gamma_star,interpolation='none')
            plt.title("Gamma_bar({}) between uniform([0,1]) and uniform([1,2])".format(5**i))

        plt.show()

        return

    # The transport between U01 ans U12 is x -> x-1 so the support of gamma^* is contained in the graph of the function x -> (x,x-1) which is the line y = x-1

    plot_Sinkhorn_U01_U12()
```